How to get rid the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in chrome
How to get rid  the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in chrome while enabling setting Base url to HTTPS,
after changing secure base_url in storefront , i m getting the NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
in chrome
in regular frequent interval
How to get rid of this errors

i have tried some ways searching on google , it was not working properly
